# Best wireless ExpressCard 802.11n card for linux

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, wireless-networking, expresscard

As I have too much trouble with my internal wireless chipset under linux and I want maximum speed for my 802.11n access point I would like to have an ExpressCard-based wireless card that is fully supported under linux. Preferably native, not ndiswrapper-based.

What's the best/best supported card out there? General googling did not give me the answers I wanted.

Comment: I have thought of USB solutions, but I think they stick out too much compared to an expresscard solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I could replace my internal (atheros) miniPCI by a different one.

I bought the **Intel Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300**, MiniPCIe and it works perfectly.